# Twitter API V2 Can't get only Author Replies in Tweet Thread

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I'm using [twitter-api-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-api-v2) to get tweet replies by id, and it working, but the query isn't.

This is my code:

```
 const data = await client.v2.search("123456789", {
    "query": "from:username to:'username'",
    "expansions": ["author_id"]
  });

  console.log(data.tweets);
```

*(username is the actual username of a twitter profile)*

I got the query from the [Twitter Query Builder](https://developer.twitter.com/apitools/query?query=Rjp1c2VyIFQ6InVzZXJuYW1lIg%3D%3D)

I'm getting the default limit of 10 tweets, but some of the are from users that are not the author, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: Why do `to:'username'` have quotes and `from:username` not ?

Answer (score 0):

> but some of the are from users that are not the author

this is because of `to:'username'`, this refers to the tweets that are in reply to a tweet of the user defined by `username`.

[image]

try removing the `to` query.